# ReduxSaga makes my website re-render infinite

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

Im using Redux-Saga and Redux-Thunk, this is store I have configured, but it makes my website re-render infinitely. Can u tell me what should i do to solve that? Thank u.

Store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from '@redux-saga/core'

import EmployeeReducer from './reducers/EmployeeReducer'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import axiosMiddleware from "redux-axios-middleware";
import HttpService from "app/services/HttpService";
import RootReducer from './reducers/RootReducer'
import {getEmployeeList} from './saga'


const initialState = {};
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const middlewares = [
  thunk,
  sagaMiddleware,
  axiosMiddleware(HttpService.getAxiosClient())
];
export const Store = createStore(
  RootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
  )
);
sagaMiddleware.run(getEmployeeList)
```

This is saga.js where i import getEmployeeList

```js
import { call, cancel, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import axios from 'axios'
import { GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST } from './actions/EmployeeActions'
import ConstantList from '../../app/appConfig'

const API_PATH = ConstantList.API_ENPOINT + "/employees"

export function* getEmployeeList() {
    yield takeEvery(GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST, workEmployeeList)
}

export function* workEmployeeList() {
    console.trace("hello");
    try {
        const url = API_PATH + '/search'
        const response = yield call(axios.post, url, {})

        yield put({
            type: GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST,
            payload: response.data.data
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Request failed!")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If it has to do with saga, it probably has to do with the code you wrote - `getEmployeeList`. You need to share that. Apart from that: you are writing an extremely outdated (pre-2019) Redux style here and also we do not recommend using sagas for simple tasks like data fetching (or really, not for everything except 0.5% of use cases) any more. Please see [why RTK is Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Comment: I have add saga.js where i import getEmployeeList. many thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the same action type to start the saga & to store the results to redux store.

```js
// here you are waiting for GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST to trigger the saga
yield takeEvery(GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST, workEmployeeList)

// here you are using the same action type to store
// response data to redux store
yield put({
    type: GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST,
    payload: response.data.data
})
```

Because of that every time you finish fetching data another saga is triggered.

What you want is to have another action type to store the data in redux store like `FETCH_EMPLOYEE_LIST_SUCCESS`. Don't forget to update your reducer condition to use the correct action type as well.

Answer (score 0):

You built yourself an infinite loop here:

```js
    yield takeEvery(GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST, workEmployeeList)
```

this means: "every time, `GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST` is dispatched, execute `workEmployeeList`"

And in `workEmployeeList` you have:

```js
    yield put({
        type: GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST,
        payload: response.data.data
    })
```

this means "dispatch `GET_EMPLOYEE_LIST`".

So 1. leads to 2. and 2. leads to 1.

I can't really suggest anything to fix this as this is missing a lot of building blocks to work in the first place.

But what I can tell you is that we as Redux maintainers really recommend against using sagas for tasks like data fetching.

If you want to know about the backgrounds, I would recommend you watch [the evolution of Redux Async Logic](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/05/presentations-evolution-redux-async-logic/).

But generally, seeing you are just getting into Redux, my advice would be to really take a step back and go through our [official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) first.
Not only shows it modern (post-2019) Redux which is about 1/4 of the code you are writing here and a lot less confusing, but it also shows multiple different approaches to data fetching.